the difference between inner join and left join
I am straggling to understand the difference between the use of join and left join in this hacker rank example.
I used the normal join but the answer was wrong and looked it up I saw the solution with left join
SELECT con.contest_id, con.hacker_id, con.name, SUM(sg.total_submissions), SUM(sg.total_accepted_submissions),
SUM(vg.total_views), SUM(vg.total_unique_views)
FROM Contests AS con 
JOIN Colleges AS col
ON con.contest_id = col.contest_id
JOIN Challenges AS cha 
ON cha.college_id = col.college_id
left  JOIN
(SELECT ss.challenge_id, SUM(ss.total_submissions) AS total_submissions, SUM(ss.total_accepted_submissions) AS total_accepted_submissions FROM 
Submission_Stats AS ss GROUP BY ss.challenge_id) AS sg
ON cha.challenge_id = sg.challenge_id
 left JOIN
(SELECT vs.challenge_id, SUM(vs.total_views) AS total_views, SUM(total_unique_views) AS total_unique_views FROM View_Stats AS vs GROUP BY vs.challenge_id) AS vg
ON cha.challenge_id = vg.challenge_id
GROUP BY con.contest_id, con.hacker_id, con.name
HAVING SUM(sg.total_submissions)+
       SUM(sg.total_accepted_submissions)+
       SUM(vg.total_views)+
       SUM(vg.total_unique_views) > 0
ORDER BY con.contest_id;

here is the code
If we are going to filter out the null values at the end anyways then what is the difference ?

You are filtering on both submission stats and view stats. If you do an inner join on the first "Submission_stats" table, you lose the rows that have no submission stats - but they could have view stats. Try to compare the output of both queries with and without left joins.
In general when you follow an inner join with a left join, the initial exclusion of non-matching rows by the inner join means that those rows are already lost. The subsequent left join will not be able to recover those excluded rows because they are no longer part of the intermediate result set.
